# Weird warning message keeps appearing in Eclipse/Pydev/Pylint

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pylint, pylintrc

I'm using Eclipse Neon with PyDev, Pylint3 (pylintrc configured) and I have the a pylint warning message in a blank line. It was true the first time it appeared, but after modifying the code, it didn't disappear.

After that, I moved the code and a blank line remained in the same line, but the warning message keeps there and there's no way of removing it.

I attach down here the image with the message and the image without the message.

This is my peculiar message:
[image: this is the warning]

in a blank line where nothing is written, as you may appreciate in this other image: [image: the line is blank]

How can I "clean" this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange but it seems like cutting all the file content, saving it and pasting it again making a second "save" did the trick and now the weird message is not there.

The others work as usual.

If it happens to you, just mess with the source code and make the message disappear and try restoring the file afterwards in any way.

Comment: As a note, the next release fixes an issue in where the PyLint executable could end up skipping a file to be analyzed depending on the number of files to be analyzed (so, it shouldn't happen anymore after PyDev 5.6.0).

Comment: Thanks for the info, @FabioZadrozny